# cv2.circle(img=frame, center=(x, y), radius=20, color=(0, 255, 255)) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'c

Tags: python, opencv

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\manis\PycharmProjects\AiMouse\main.py", line 30, in 
cv2.circle(img=frame, center=(x, y), radius=20, color=(0, 255, 255))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'circle'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
> - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

Comment: include code segments. looks like x is being set to a non int value at some point before line 30

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `x,y` must be integer. you need to review [ask]. you did not search for previous questions on that error message.

Comment: Don't used keyword. Should be like this.. cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 20, (0, 255, 255))